# Import a javascript array in a typescript file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript

I have a file named array.js which contains a huge number of strings. 
Something like this :

```
module.exports = ["word1","word2",...]
```

I want to use this array in my validation.ts file so what I did was :

```
let wiki = require('./array.js');
```

but when I run my tests it says :

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/out/array.js
[1] Chrome 53.0.2785 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
[1]   {
[1]     "originalErr": {}
[1]   }
[1] WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/out/array.js
[1] Firefox 52.0.0 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) ERROR
[1]   {
[1]     "stack": "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading out/array.js\n\t\n\tError loading out/array.js as \"./array.js\" from out/validation.js",
[1]     "originalErr": {}
[1]   }
```

I don't know what is the problem

Comment: I means that the web server returned 404 (not found) for the URL `/base/out/array.js`. So you need to look at why that is. Perhaps the URL you're using with `require` is wrong. Perhaps your SystemJS setup is wrong. *We* certainly can't tell you, it's something you have to debug at your end.

Comment: In my out folder there's no array.js that's why it's not found I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your path to the array file is correct, change `let wiki = require('./array.js');` to `let wiki = require('./array');`

Comment: I already did that but it doesn't work. The problem is that the array.js is not found in my out folder that's why I got the error.